# Whether it will alert?

Tags: javascript, html

is this correct

```
<a href="#" style="color:#FFF;"onclick="add('alert("Google !")');" id="cricket" tabindex="1" name="cricket">cricket</a>
```

Comment: The answer depends on what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick="add('alert("Google !")');"` is being parsed as:

```
onclick        # attribute name
=
"add('alert("  # string
Google !       # random garbage
")');"         # another string
```

You'll have to escape the inner quotes, otherwise they terminate the string:

```
onclick="add('alert(&quot;Google !&quot;)');"
```

Beyond that, it depends on what `add()` does.

Comment: I don't think backslashes work like that in HTML. I've been able to find XSS holes in websites because they use `addslashes` there, where it really doesn't apply.

Comment: @Matchu Long fixed. Working too little with HTML lately... ;)

Answer (score 1):

No.

```
onclick="add('alert("
```

You don't have a complete JavaScript statement inside your attribute value.

> Some authors use the character entity reference "`&quot;`" to encode instances of the double quote mark (") since that character may be used to delimit attribute values.

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/charset.html#h-5.3

(And as an aside:

- Don't use href="#", [build on stuff that works](http://icant.co.uk/articles/pragmatic-progressive-enhancement/#build)
- Don't use the style attribute, separate presentation and content
- Don't forget to put spaces between your attributes
- Don't use intrinsic event attributes (such as onclick), use [unobtrusive JS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) (which would also solve the problem of the nested quotes)
- Where possible, avoid tabindex in favour of a sensible natural tab order
  )